# How does Moovweb 5 Modes work for Tablet and Mobile?

Tags: layer, moovweb, modesetting

Gone through the API (http://developer.moovweb.com/docs/cloud/modes) but in Moovweb 5 did not find the place to set regular expression for Modes.

How can we set the regex expression in modes?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 parts to this answer, the regular expression support that was available in Moovweb 4.x and regular expression support added to route modes in Moovweb 5.

In Moovweb 5 you have the ability to create one or multiple modes (as opposed to Moovweb 4.x) under a single project. Each mode could represent a specific experience for a given endpoint, in M5 you can use predefined criteria to target either mobile or tablet devices. This instead of writing the expression yourself as in Moovweb 4.x

Is that what you refer to?

JC